# Do written languages evolve along the lines of the script?

Tags: written-language, sound-change, persian

The medieval sound changes of New Persian are suggestive of tracing back ultimately to the script, so as if to normalize the writting by adjusting the underlying spoken language.

Thus the majhul and ma'ruf vowels ī/ē and ū/ō which are written the same coincide and nearly all sounds indicated by ه at the end of words become -e, irrespective of whither they go back.

Are there instances known of written, "classical" but not artificial languages where phonological changes were or may have been prompted by the script?

Comment: You may want to clarify what types of phonological changes would be acceptable. It is well known that spelling pronunciation influences how individual words are pronounced (e.g. forehead, Birmingham, etc.) so it would not be surprising if this lead to systematic phonological change. However, I don't know of any examples off hand. On the other hand, the presence of ubiquitous orthography does not seem to prevent vowel mergers such as LOT / THOUGHT in modern American English. Nor does it reinstate former distinctions such as Y/I in Czech. So you would need lots of evidence for systematic claims.

Comment: @DominikLukes, as for the cot-caught merger, maybe one can argue that very non-phonemic orthographies are less likely to influence phonology. I'm not sure if the cot/caught vowels are completely predictable from the spelling, but at the very least it's not a simple one-to-one mapping.

Comment: As far as I know, Afghan dialects of Persian still keep some of those distinctions that have largely dissappeared in Iran, especially in Tehran dialect. Was literacy more widespread in Iran in Medieval times than in its Eastern neighbour? It could be an easy test to check if spelling pronunciations forced the regularization and expansion of the sound changes.

Answer (score 2):

Russian is an example of such a language.

In Russian there are two distinct letters `e` and `ё`, after a consonant letter `e` is pronounced as ['e] and `ё` as ['o], the apostrophe means the preceding consonant sound is palatalized:

> мел [m'el] 'chalk'
>
> мёл [m'ol] 'swept'

But the point is that, as a distinct letter, `ё` was introduced rather recently, in the 18th century, and its usage was usually arbitrary, one could always write `e` instead, besides many typewriters had no `ё` key, for technical reasons, so all that resulted in confusion of the two letters, mostly in borrowed words, and in mispronouncing of some others, which was so widespread that some of those mispronounced variants became the norm now.

For example, Leo Tolstoy's name in standard modern Russian is `Лев [l'ef] Толстой`, but his actual name was `Лёв [l'of]`, and 99% of Russians are unaware of this. Other examples include:

- Goebbels: the correct Г**ё**ббельс is now changed to Г**e**ббельс (the same thing with Göring, Röhm, Montesquieu, Richelieu, and Röntgen, pronounced with [e] in modern Russian);
- мушкетёр 'musketeer' and фуникулёр 'funicular' - the French words from which these two were borrowed ended in -aire, so in Russian they should have had the final [e], still it is [o] now;
- аф**е**ра 'fraud, affair' and гренад**е**р 'grenadier' are commonly mispronounced with [o], although the official dictionaries say it must be [e].

Still, as you can see, this affects some specific groups of words, in native Russian words nobody mixes up the two letters.

Also, your question is connected with [hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), like [H-adding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection#H-adding) etc., that happens in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that any of these changes can be explained in terms of the script. All Old Iranian final short vowels were lost already in Middle Persian. New Persian final –a (Western Persian –e) is from Middle Persian –ag. This is why /a/ is virtually the only final short vowel in New Persian.

Comment: But at least the Ṭā Marbūṭa of Arabic loans does not come from mp. -ag. And is really every Early New Persian final -a from this source? The past (= perfect) participles as well as for instance the preposition "be"?

Comment: We can leave the Arabic loans out of this. The (neo-)perfect-participle of the type karda is from (or by analogy to) MP de-verbal nouns like kardag, Iranian *kṛ-ta-ka-. The preposition ba (Early NP pa) is from MP pad, Old Persian pati. So yes, the -a of ba does not come from –ag.

Comment: I should have said "is usually from MP -ag".

Comment: But don't the loans give a good clue? Those that were borrowed before New Persian vowel shift must have shifted along with the "native" New Persian a-finals while those that were borrowed after that (if any?) must have been borrowed (by analogy of the script?) directly as e-final.

Comment: This shift of -a > -e is late, and does not affect all dialects of Persian.

Comment: Or better: [ɛ] is an allophone of /a/ in word final position in some Persian dialects.

Comment: How late is that shift? Not contemporary with the loss of distinction between majhul and ma'ruf vowels?

Comment: For the maʻrūf and majhūl vowels there is this article by the late Fritz Meier:
www.jstor.org/stable/1580565